# How do I send props to a custom TabBar?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just created a custom BottomTabBar and I have some shared components where I would like to hide the tab bar while the component is active.

My question is how do I send the component state to the tab bar?

Here is my Navigator

```
export default (LoggedInTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Explore: {
      screen: Explore,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: CustomTabBarIcon("layers", 32)
      }
    },
    SavedTab: {
      screen: SavedTab,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: CustomTabBarIcon("heart", 32)
      }
    },
    AddPost: {
      screen: AddPost,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: CustomTabBarIcon("plus", 32)
      }
    },
    Chat: {
      screen: Chat,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: CustomTabBarIcon("email", 32)
      }
    },
    More: {
      screen: More,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: CustomTabBarIcon("dots-horizontal", 32)
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: props => <BottomTabBar {...props} />
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        marginBottom: 5
      },
      activeTintColor: colors.white,
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: colors.dark
      }
    },
    tabBarPosition: "bottom"
  }
));
```

Now I would like to send the component state `isVisible` to `tabBarComponent` something like

```
onPress={() =>
   this.setState({
      isVisible: true
   })
}
```

I know that I can send props to screen like `this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen', {isVisible})` but this works only if I go on another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about using ScreenProps would this work

```
import LoggedInTabNavigator from './LoggedInTabNavigator';

<LoggedInTabNavigator screenProps={{ isVisible: this.state.isVisible}} />
```

you can then access this from

```
this.props.screenProps.isVisible
```